# Laravel Multihauth: To be or Not to Be?

Tags: laravel, authentication

I am building an app and will need multi auth to works well. First, users that will log as employees using table users with email and password. I´m using Voyager as backend and using roles and permissions. So far, so good. Now I have another kind of user: they are registered on an ERP and I reach then via WS using CPF (like the social-secure number) and password stored in ERP. Then I get then and record at a table all the data I need. It is working well as good. Well, was working. For those users, I used the API route, just not to make a mess on my web routes file. Yesterday I ran PHP artisan make:auth and that´s when things start to get crazy.

Every axios call now returns me an 'unauthorized' message cause, obviously, they´re not authenticated.

What would be better?

Refactory Users login to use CPF instead of email and give a new role for those others API guys and make then pass trough web.php file like everybody?
Use a multiauth package?
Or anything else?
Please, help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me, a user is a user. It seems to be a common thing that if an application has more than one “type” of user, that developers instantly start creating multiple Eloquent models, then guards, then controllers, then views, and so on; and then find themselves in a mess when they need a route that can be accessed by more than one type of user.

Instead, elevate “type” to its own model and add it as a relation to your `User` model. If a user can only be of one type, then make it a one-to-many relation. If a user can have many roles, then make it a belongs-to-many relation. You then use [authorization](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authorization) to determine whether a user can access a route based on the role(s) they have.

Comment: and if the different users should not access the information the same way (limitation by type), you add a bunch of `if`/`switch` everywhere. If some role depend on another model, add an `if` on every controller method shared by those two user types. Just to say Roles are Roles and Different Entities can't be all assimilated to the same Entity.

Comment: @Martin Bean. You are absolutely right. A user is a user, period. I´ll refactor it to goes this way. Will create a role more and make then login as normal users. If he is not on my DB it is ´cause it is they´re here the first time and I will look via WS for their credentials and save at my database.
THanks a lot for sharing your point of view!

Comment: @N69S “and if the different users should not access the information the same way (limitation by type), you add a bunch of if/switch everywhere.” Not necessarily. That would be one of the very few scenarios I’d maybe suggest a repository.

Comment: @MartinBean a repository to manage session level code ? i mean, what will you be putting in that repository ?

Comment: @N69S What will you be putting in your application with multiple user models? Lots of `if ($user instanceof T)` calls…?

Comment: @N69S I fail to see how passing a user as an argument is “session-level”. I thought it was just called “passing an argument to a method”.

Comment: you make your repository depending on who is logged in. you will be implementing middleware work in your repository

Comment: @N69S Not really. Pass a user to a repository method, get results for that user.